# Programming nRF24LE1 with an Amontec JTAG key

Tags: programmer, 8051

I'm a bit lost on how to program my nRF24LE1 with the Amontec JTAG key that I have. It seems as if it's possible, but I cant find any information on how to. On their website, on the contrary, there is too much information, and I cant figure out what is relevant. If anyone knows, any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can we get links directly to the chip and product. This greatly increases the answers given.

Answer (score 1):

The Amontec JTAG Key is intended for debugging and programming ARM systems. It isn't suitable for use with the nRF24LE1 (8051).

Comment: I would have posted this as a comment.